# Wordpress redirecting users after login -> only working for administrators

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am trying to redirect users in my child theme "functions.php" usint the following code:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect1', 10, 3 );

function custom_login_redirect( ) {
     if ( $user && is_object( $user ) ) {
        
         if ( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $url = admin_url();
         } 
         else if ($user->has_cap( 'voc_edit_events' ) ) {
            $url = home_url( '/pieces/' );
         }
         else {
            $url = home_url( '/protokolle/' );
         }
    }
    return $url;
}

function custom_login_redirect1(){
    if ($user && is_object( $user)) {
        if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
            if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
                $url = admin_url();
            }
            elseif (in_array('voc_edit_events', $user->roles)) {
                $url = home_url( '/pieces/' );
            }
            else {
                $url = home_url( '/protokolle/' );
            }
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

I actually tried both focusing on capabilities or roles to redirect users.
Whatever code I am using I only partially successful.

This means that only users with the administrator role get redirected to the admin_url and all others will not be redirected.

Based on how I understand the code I would assume that

- Administrators --> admin_url
- Users with 'voc_edit_events' role --> /pieces/
- all others --> /protokolle/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these codes

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wp98_custom_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
function wp98_custom_login_redirect( $url, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        if ( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $url = admin_url();
        } elseif ( $user->has_cap( 'voc_edit_events' ) ) {
            $url = home_url( '/pieces/' );
        } else {
            $url = home_url( '/protokolle/' );
        }
    }
    
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this code works - however I also discovered that there was a plugin intefering with this redirect --> but it works now - thanks!